# Updating a field in an Access DB that has a list selection

Tags: .net, database, powershell, oledb, ms-access-2013

I am trying to edit an access .accdb file in Powershell using OLEDB and I'm golden except for one field.  It's a type 203 adLongVarwChar ( Long Text ) but has a set of items it can be. i.e "Operations", "Sales", "Credit".  when you look at this on Sharepoint or in Access you are presented a drop down box to select one or more entries.  In code I can only retrieve one of these selections... ( I can show connection if needed but I'm not sure that matters here )

```
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Business Impact").Value
```

this only returns one of the options even if multiple are selected.

The information from Access is as follows:

- Display Control ( Combo Box )
- Row Source Type ( Value List )
- Row Source ( "Operations"; "Sales"; "Credit" )
- Limit to List ( Yes )

if I do this...

```
$objRecordSet.AddNew()
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Business Impact").Value = "Operations"
```

I get this error:

> Exception setting "Value": "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Business Impact").value = "test"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValueTI

Any other field works just fine.....just not this one.. does anyone know of a way to edit this field.... I've done many searches on the net and I can find MANY pages on how to edit the data.. but NONE talk about this type of field.

When I view this in excel, the data is stored like this "Operations";#"Sales"  setting the value = using that format also doesn't work.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of newer Access features that cannot be fully exploited using Access SQL because they involve hidden child tables that don't "fit" well in the normal SQL way of doing things. Those features are:

- multi-value Lookup fields (like the one you are using), and
- Attachment fields (which can hold multiple attachments).

To insert, update, and delete individual items within these fields you need to use the `Recordset` and `Recordset2` objects in ACE DAO.

For a table named [LookupTest] like this ...

[image: OldRecord.png]

... the following Excel VBA code adds a new record with "Sales" and "Credit" selected.

```vbs
Sub AddRecordWithMultipleListLookupValues()
    Dim dbe As Object  ' DAO.DBEngine
    Dim db As Object  ' DAO.Database
    Dim rstMain As Object  ' DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstLookup As Object  ' DAO.Recordset2
    Const dbOpenDynaset = 2

    Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
    Set rstMain = db.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT ID, [Business Impact] FROM LookupTest", _
            dbOpenDynaset)
    rstMain.AddNew  ' ID is AutoNumber
    Set rstLookup = rstMain.Fields("Business Impact").Value
    rstLookup.AddNew
    rstLookup.Fields("Value").Value = "Sales"
    rstLookup.Update
    rstLookup.AddNew
    rstLookup.Fields("Value").Value = "Credit"
    rstLookup.Update
    rstLookup.Close
    rstMain.Update
    rstMain.Close
    db.Close

    Set rstLookup = Nothing
    Set rstMain = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set dbe = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: NewRecord.png]

It shouldn't be too difficult to translate that VBA code into PowerShell.

Also, speaking of PowerShell, since it is built on .NET you may find that ODBC works better than OLEDB when performing SELECTs on these types of Lookup fields. At least in C#, ODBC will return a string similar to the screenshots above, while OLEDB cannot.

Comment: Thanks for that very concise and helpful answer.  I switched to using ODBC and not OLEDB ( connectionstrings listed that one first I tried it and it worked lol ).  I am now able to use those commands to update the data as I need.  Thanks!!